# Inputting a pre-existing value into a bootstrap 4 select form

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

just a basic question.

I am currently creating a form using bootstrap 4 in which the user can select a person from a database and have the data automatically inputted into the correct boxes. This is all fine and dandy up until I reach my one select option. Usually to input the data into the correct form I would use the line `value="{{ data }}"`, however this does not work for the select form as the value attribute is disallowed. The code I have attempted is here:

```
<select class="form-control" value="{{ data }}" name="name">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
</select>
</label>
```

Say the user specified a specific person from my database on this form, and that person had option3 saved as their choice for that option, how would I go about having that automatically inputted for the user?
Thanks.

Comment: So very basic that you can find an answer almost anywhere that teaches the basics of html: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp

Comment: As far as I know Bootstrap on its own it not used to pre-populate or pre-input a form. You can use jQuery / PHP / ASP.NET / VueJS and a lot more technologies to populate the "value" attribute of an HTML form element. It depends on your tech stack.